# How to iterate the array in react native in a function and use it inside the render() method. a valid React element (or null) must be returned.

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am a new bee to react native, I am unable to render the items using maps in when I create a function outside the render function.

If I provide normal returns it works ex :

```
function(props){
return <Text> Hello </Text>
}
```

But when I am trying to iterate than it does not. please tell me whats wrong in function **function Xyz(x)** in below code.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, SectionList, StyleSheet, Text, View , Button} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'


class SectionListBasics extends Component {

constructor(props){
  super(props);


}

data = {
     "data": {
       "driver": {
         "name": "Sangesh",
         "phone": "07453520814"
       },
       "store": [
         {
           "host": "s-447.t2scdn.com",
           "name": "DEV - s-447.t2scdn.com",
           "license_key": "123",
           "driver_id": "56769"
         },
         {
           "host": "s-519.t2scdn.com",
           "name": "DEV - s-519.t2scdn.com",
           "license_key": "345",
           "driver_id": "56815"
         }        

       ]
     }
   }



  render() {
    return (
        <View>
        <Xyz c={this.data}/>       

      </View>


    );
  }
}




function Xyz(x) {

      return (x.c.data.store.map((index) => { <Text> {index.host} </Text> }))

}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SectionListBasics)
```

The custom **Xyz** is not working.

Its keeps on throwing below error :

[image]

Comment: The `render()` function does not have a `return` keyword, so it returns `undefined`. Does returning the `Xyz` element in the `render()` method fix that error?

Comment: Sorry I have updated in question, but still issue isn't resolved.

Comment: `Xyz` returns the result of `map`, which is an Array. You need to wrap it inside an element, like this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing a silly mistake

**Working code**

```
function Xyz(x) {
  return (
    <View>
      {x.c.data.store.map((item) => (<Text> {item.name} </Text>))}
    </View>
  )
}
```

**Wrong Code (mistake was in syntax)**

```
function Xyz(x) {
  return (
    <View>
      {x.c.data.store.map((item) => { <Text> {item.name} </Text> })}
    </View>
  )
}
```

this piece of code should be wrapped in () instead of {}
`{<Text> {item.name} </Text>}` ---to--->>  `(<Text> {item.name} </Text>)`

By changing it works. puting in this {} It was treating as jsx. Also importantly while returning it should be wrapped in a **View**

Comment: The issue was you weren't returning anything, without `{ }`, it does an implicit return but this would work too `{ return <Text> {item.name} </Text> }`

Answer (score 0):

inside return:

```
{
  someData.map((item) => (
    <Xyz
      key={itemId}
      custom={item.field}
    />
  ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not an object so you can't do `x.c.data.store.map(...)`.

Try parsing the JSON first or use an object as data.

Comment: I have checked **typeof** its an object.